# How can i refresh asp.net main web form from child web form

Tags: asp.net

I have two web form in my asp.net project,in the web form number 1 i have a button and i write this code for open the web form number 2:

```
Response.Write("<script> var myWindow = window.open('DatePicker.aspx', '', 'width=400, height=500');</script>");
```

when open web form number 2 ,i want when close the web form number 2 ,web form number 1 refresh,for that reason i write this code on the web form number 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RefreshParent() {
            if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
                window.opener.location.reload();
                window.close(); // ADDED LINE
            }
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = RefreshParent;
    </script>
```

But web form number 1 not reload,what happen?

Comment: have you tried window.location="WebformNumber1.aspx"?

Comment: Hi my friend,how can i write that tried?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function RefreshParent() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
           window.location= "webformnumber1.aspx"; 
        }
    }
```

Also make sure your code inside if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) condition is executing